# Could I get my form data from formspark with js fetch() API?

Tags: javascript, fetch

As I read from [formspark documentation](https://documentation.formspark.io/examples/ajax.html#ajax-submissions) we can use `GET` methods in formspark. If I understood correctly, the `GET` method in JS fetch() API means that we want to retrieve data from somewhere. So I wrote this code to get my data (data that were created before from submissions in formspark) with JS fetch method:

```js
async function fetchText() {
    let response = await fetch('https://submit-form.com/my-id', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        }
    })
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

fetchText().then(r => console.log(r));
```

But it gives me an empty object as a response data! while I have six submissions in my account now. Could someone please help me that what is **wrong** in my code?

Comment: You aren't POSTing or PUTting JSON in the request body so `"Content-Type": "application/json"` is a lie.

Comment: From the documentation link, it seems that you can use fetch to submit forms, but not retrieve them. Also, it wouldn't make sense if it could work then way because than the data would be public.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your comment. I learned from that, but it does not change the situation, again I receive empty object.

Comment: @Sophia Koulen thanks for your comment. My problem is **exactly** that the documentation does not show any example of using ```GET``` method. And about public that you said, I think not all form data are sensible. For example you may want to show a welcome message with the name of user that submitted to your form.

Answer (score 0):

The backend returns the following message `This form does not exist anymore`.

[image: Server error]

If I do the same with the URL sample from the documentation. It gives me the following error

[image: Another server error]

So what do you need to do is to replace the `my-id` with your form ID in the URL (e.g `https://submit-form.com/22`).

Here is the snippet with the change applied

```js
async function fetchText(formId) {
    let response = await fetch(`https://submit-form.com/${formId}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        }
    })
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

const targetFormId = 441; // Here should be a valid actual form ID

fetchText(targetFormId).then(r => console.log(r));
```

Comment: I know that I must put my own id instead of ```my-id```, but I did not want to show my-id in public.

Comment: @hamid-davodi Could you create a sample form with sample submissions and share it with us, so we can experiment with it?